# ECC encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption

I have used the ECC encryption algorithm to encrypt my data. Now I need to compare the time complexity involved in it with another algorithm. I need to know, what is the time complexity for encrypting a data using the ECC algorithm

Comment: What do you mean by "the ECC encryption algorithm"? ECIES? And what precisely do you mean by "time complexity"? For practical purposes you should *measure* or check existing benchmarks (e.g. [eBACS](http://bench.cr.yp.to/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get usable real world data for your situation would be to simply test it and create your own benchmarks.

Try running 1000 operations with ECC and 1000 with RSA, and measure the time.

This is because while there some guidelines to the complexity of an algorithm there are many other factors such as how that algorithm is used as well as the platform it is used on. For example one really good JavaScript implementation of RSA could perhaps outperform a poorly implemented but supposedly faster algorithm such as ECC.

Time complexity is often not as critical as the implementation. Unless you have something a few degrees higher and tons of rounds, and anyone who has done work with limits in calculus knows the impact of this over time. i.e: N^5/N^2 where N is lets say 100 million messages or something